# ElasticSearch: How to search for a value in any field, across all types, in one or more indices?

Tags: elasticsearch, match

I have two indices `my_index_1` and `my_index_2`.  Within these indices, I have the following document types:

`my_index_1`:

- people
- organizations
- roles
- skills

`my_index_2`:

- products
- services
- patents
- trademarks
- servicemarks

Each of the types has different fields.

**My Question:** *What is the best way to query for the string "abc" in any field of any type, across any one or even both indices?*

I don't see anything in the documentation that facilitates such a search.  Is there something that might look like:

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match": { *: "abc" } }
}'
```

Thanks, in advance, for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Either the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) or the [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) would be what you're looking for.

`query_string` will use the special [`_all` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) if none is specified in `default_field`, so that would work out well.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": { "query_string": { "query": "abc" } }
}'
```

And with `match` you can just specify the `_all` as well.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": { "match": { "_all": "abc" } }
}'
```

Note that with `query_string` you may use wildcards, which you can't with `match`

---

**UPDATE:**

As the `_all` field was deprecated in 6.0, the solution is now to implement a [custom all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/mapping-all-field.html#custom-all-fields)

Comment: Hi Val.  Thanks for both options.  I can use the match with _all, for now, but I'll definitely have to look deeper into the query_string as I'm going to need to use wildcards, in the future.  So, it's great to know.

Comment: Plz note that _all is deprecated in 6.0.0 [See here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html)

Comment: @FaisalMq Yes, the solution is now to implement a [custom all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-all.html)

Answer (score 38):

An alternative to the now deprecated [_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/mapping-all-field.html) field is the [multi match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html)

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query":    "Will Smith",
      "fields": [ "important_field^5", "less_important^2", "title", "*_name" ] 
    }
  }
}
```

Note wildcards in the field names are supported as well as boosting a fields importance with the ^# syntax

As of version 7.3:
If no fields are provided, the multi_match query defaults to the index.query.default_field index settings, which in turn defaults to *. * extracts all fields in the mapping that are eligible to term queries and filters the metadata fields. All extracted fields are then combined to build a query.

Another alternative is the [Query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
            "default_field" : "content"
        }
    }
}
```

default_field
(Optional, string) Default field you wish to search if no field is provided in the query string.

Defaults to the index.query.default_field index setting, which has a default value of *.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the most relevant answer at this point. Helped me out a lot!

Comment: Although Val's answer was also correct, this one was the most informative/relevant for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to get the result of all indices and all fields:

```
GET _all/_search
{
"query" : {
   "multi_match": {
      "query": "abc",
      "fields": []
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html?q=_all) for this purpose

Try this

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '
{
  "query": { "match": { "_all": "abc" } }
}'
```

You could also use [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) as it searches against `_all` by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was using version 8.3 of Elasticsearch and none of this worked for me.

Worked me:

```
public function search($text)
{

    $client = $this->setClient();

    $params   = $this->transferRequiredFormat($text);
    $response = $client->search($params, $info = false);


    printf("Total docs: %d\n", $response['hits']['total']['value']);
    printf("Max score : %.4f\n", $response['hits']['max_score']);
    printf("Took      : %d ms\n", $response['took']);
    dd($response['hits']['hits']);


}

private function setClient()
{
    return ClientBuilder::create()->setHosts(['localhost:9200'])->build();
}

protected function transferRequiredFormat($text): array
{
    return [
        'index' => self::INDEX_NAME,
        'body'  => [
            'query' => [
                'query_string' => [
                    'query' => $text,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Or a short survey [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-query-ex-request)

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(new york city) OR (big apple)",
      "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index1,my_index2',
        'from'=>0,
        'size'=>10,
        'body'  => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'filter' => [
                        [
                            'query_string' => [
                                'query' => "info*"
                                //'query' => "*info*"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).