# java code for dynamically generated fields for wildcard search in elastic search

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, service

Is there a way to get all field names of elastic search in java.
I am looking for a solution to get a wildcard elastic search for all fields.

QueryBuilder queryBuilder=QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("metaDataInfo.fileName",".*"+queryValue+".*");

the above solution is for a single field. Need to get all field names from java code as field names may change with respect to different indexes.

Comment: What do you mean 'dynamically'? What whould be the source?

Comment: here dynamically means fields generated with respect to different indexes. Basically looking for search in all fields available in source.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElasticSearch: How to search for a value in any field, across all types, in one or more indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147471/elasticsearch-how-to-search-for-a-value-in-any-field-across-all-types-in-one)

Comment: @Lefteris the above solution is not working.

Comment: I am looking for search one particular index at a time and the fields may differ for different indexes.

Comment: Can we combine multimatch query with regexpquery?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.